# How do I query django parent and child by a one to many relationship?

Tags: python, django, sqlite, django-views

So I am fairly new to django and I am trying to create a website keeps a log of who took out their families' dogs last. I have made my models to include tables for each individual post, dog, and their actions that correspond with the posts themselves. I want to make it so that a list of posts will be placed in order of latest to earliest post followed by all of the actions that each dog did (i.e. if there are two dog objects then there will be two action objects that accompany the post).

models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Dog(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 20)

class Post(models.Model):
    walker = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    time_posted = models.DateTimeField(default = timezone.now)
    issues = models.TextField(max_length = 300)

class Action(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    dog = models.ForeignKey(Dog, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    peed = models.BooleanField(default = False)
    pooped = models.BooleanField(default = False)
```

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import ListView, CreateView
from .models import Post, Dog, Action
from django.http import HttpResponse

class ActionList(ListView):

def home(request):
    context = {
        'posts': Post.objects.all(),
        'actions': Action.objects.all(),
        'dogs': Dog.objects.all()
    }
    return render(request, 'dog_log_app/home.html', context)
```

main.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Home</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <h1>Home</h1>
        <!-- displays user info -->
        {% if user.is_authenticated %}
        <h2>Current Logged in User is {{request.user.username}}</h2>
        <a href = "{% url 'logout' %}">Logout</a>
        {% else %}
            <a href = "{% url 'login' %}">Login</a>
            <a href = "{% url 'register' %}">Register</a>
        {% endif %}
        <br>
        <h2>Posts:</h2>
        {% for post in posts %}
            <h3>person walking: {{post.walker}}</h3>
            <h4>time walked: {{post.time_posted}}</h4>
            <h4>issues: {{post.issues}}</h4>
            {% for action in actions %}
                {{ACTIONS CORRESPONDING TO POST}}
            {% endfor %}
            
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

What the ideal post would look like:

- Walker: [generic_user]
- Time walked: [date and time]
- Issues: [any issues]
- Dog1: Peed and Pooped
- Dog2: Pooped

I know how to format the action data to make it look like the way it is above. I simply am having a hard time trying to join the action objects with the post object.
If any of this is confusing I apologize. Post below for anything that needs clarification. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the reverse of a `ForeignKey` through a manager that has the same name as the [**`related_name=…` parameter** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name). By default the value is `classname_set`. So in this case, you can obtain the items with:

```
{% for action in post.action_set.all %}
    …
{% endfor %}
```

you thus can write this as:

```
{% for action in post.action_set.all %}
    {{ action.dog.name }}: {% if action.peed %}peed{% endif %} {% if action.pooped %}pooped{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: oh you was so faster :)

Comment: Wow wee oh my, this helped me out so much. You have no idea how long I was stuck on this thing. Thank you so much for the help!